# AWS Athena concurrency limits: Number of submitted queries VS number of running queries

Tags: concurrency, limit, amazon-emr, amazon-athena, aws-glue

According to [AWS Athena limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html) you can submit up to 20 queries of the same type at a time, but it is a soft limit and can be increased on request. I use `boto3` to interact with Athena and my script submits 16 CTAS queries each of which takes about 2 minutes to finish. In a AWS account, it is only me who is using Athena service. However, when I look at the state of queries through console I see that only a few of queries (5 on average) are actually being executed despite all of them being in state `Running`. Here is what would normally see in Athena hisotry tab:

[image: Athena hisotry tab]

I understand that, after I submit queries to Athena, it processes the queries by assigning resources based on the overall service load and the amount of incoming requests. But I tried to run them at different days and hours, still would get about 5 queries being executed at the same time.

So my question is this how it supposed to be? If it is then what is the point of being able to submit up to 20 queries if roughly 15 of them would be idling and waiting for available slots.

### Update 2019-09-26

Just stumbled across HIVE CONNECTOR in presto documentation, which has a section [AWS Glue Catalog Configuration Properties](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#aws-glue-catalog-configuration-properties). There we can see

> `hive.metastore.glue.max-connections`: Max number of concurrent connections to Glue (defaults to 5).

This got me wonder if it has something to do with my issue. As I understand, Athena is simply a Presto that runs on EMR cluster which is configured to use AWS Glue Data Catalog as the Metastore.

So what if my issue comes from the fact that EMR cluster for Athena simply uses default value for concurrent connections to Glue, which is 5 which and is exactly of how many concurrent queries are actually getting executed (on average) in my case.

### Update 2019-11-27

The Athena team recently deployed a host of new functionality for Athena. although `QUEUED` has been in the state enum for some time is hasn't been used until now. So now I get, correct info about query state in a history tab, but everything else remains the same.

[image]

Also, [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072615/how-to-speed-up-amazon-athena-query-executions) was published with similar problem.

Comment: The Athena service limits allow you to submit up to 20 queries by default. Athena then processes these as soon as possible. What you're seeing is typical behaviour, from my experience.
The point of being able to submit 20 is that the queries will be executed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your account's limits for the Athena service is not an SLA, it's more of a priority in the query scheduler.

Depending on available capacity your queries may be queued even though you're not running any other queries. Exactly what a higher concurrency limit means is internal and could change, but in my experience it's best to think of it as the priority by which he query scheduler will deal with your query. Queries for all accounts run in the same server pool(s) and if everyone is running queries there will not be any capacity left for you.

You can see this in action by running the same query over and over again and then plot the query execution metrics over time, you will notice that they vary a lot, and you will notice spikes in the time your queries are queued on the top of every hour – when everyone else is running their scheduled queries.

Comment: So increasing number of submitted queries simply means that I can put more of them in a queue?) Ok, I get that, but what puzzles me is that I would always see 4-5 queries being in running state regardless of month, day or hour I have submitted them. I have never seen > 5.